# configuring phpmyadmin and mysql

Tags: php, apache

i just installed xampp on my pc windows 7 64bit,it seems everything was successfully installed but when i click on phpMyAdmin i get an error like this on the image below
[image]

Comment: Check if mysql is running.  When you open xampp is the mysql service running?

Comment: its running but im still getting the same error

Comment: migrating to serverfault or webmasters.stackexchange.com might yield better responses.

Comment: more like superuser.com and not serverfault as it is more of a user scenario then server.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if MySQL is started and not just Apache/PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling your firewall. If that works, look into properly creating a firewall rule for it.

In the future, these questions would be better posed in other venues (consider [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) or [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com))

Answer (score 1):

Open the command line and type in:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Enter the password (if no password set, leave off -p switch).

If you can get in, at least you know MySQL is running properly. So the fault is not there.

Check phpmyadmin's config.inc.php file. It could have wrong login mechanism set, the wrong username/password set, or is using a port number other than 3306 (default for MySQL).

Also consider trying some of the other wamp packages such as : WampServer, UniformServer, ZWamp, WampDeveloper (commercial)...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs

You might have better luck there. Just make sure to uninstall, delete, and reboot first.